# How to Unit Test a WebService call?

Tags: web-services, api, unit-testing, mocking

I have a standard web application, it contains a UI (which has an WebService API), which references a Business Layer which in turn references a SQL based DAL.  These layers have a good coverage of unit tests which use mocking to replace their dependencies.

I also have an API library which allows users to access the WS via code (and handles a lot of the issues like credentials, urls etc).  I want to write unit tests for my library.

Currently the only way I can do this is to write tests referencing the library and populate the database using the same mechanism I use to test the DAL.  However this approach is clearly flawed as it doesn't test my API library classes - it tests the entire stack!

How can I insert a mock under the WS (which is in a different project)?  I'm currently using MBUnit and MOQ to test.

EDIT: My unit tests currently test two things:

1. That the API is translating from WS objects to local objects I pass to the consumer correctly
2. That the fields of the transport objects were populated correctly

Comment: I believe you are talking about integration tests, not about unit tests

Comment: I think my goal is to unit test them... I want to be able to control what comes back over the WS call without relying on (or setting) the state of a DB

Comment: What exactly are you trying to verify that the API is doing?

Comment: @aclear16 very good question... edited to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your API really seems to be doing 2 things, so I'd place these responsibilities in 2 distinct modules and test them separately

- A Translator module. Translates API calls into web service proxy calls and maps back responses from the web service to appropriate data structures defined in the API. To test it, use a mock of the Adapter module described below.
- An Adapter / Proxy module whose job is to call the real web service. You can test it using integration tests. If the only way to do it is populate a database and exercise the full stack, you might want to move these tests out of your main test suite into a less frequent, long-running test suite.

Similar approaches are discussed here : http://blog.8thlight.com/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html and there http://nf2p.com/dot-net/mocking-web-service-proxies-using-the-adapter-pattern-to-allow-unit-testing/